# laravel 4 routing to controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm missing something on laravel routing. Here's my route:

```
Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController', array('only' => array('index')));
```

Here's the controller:

```
// AdminController.php
class AdminController extends BaseController {
/**
 * @return Response
 */
  public function index()
  {
    return 'Admin!';
  }
}
```

When I visit `/admin` I get a 404 error. I'm not sure why! I would expect `Admin!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should rename your `index()` method to `getIndex()` when your using `Route::controller`

Comment: the usage of `Route::controller` and `Route::resource` are different, you can refer to [Implicit Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers) and [RESTful Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Comment: and `Route::controller` actually only accept first two arguments, `array('only' => array('index')` only works when you use `Route::resource`

Answer (score 0):

please refer http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

```
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
```